# mysql - problems with connect and use database

Tags: mysql

When I connect to mysql sql db I get 2 errors:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104
```

or

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

Sometimes I get first one, and sometimes second one. Sometimes mysql throws this error when I try to conect to db("mysql -u root -p[PASS]") and sometimes I can connect, but after that when I try type "use somedb" or "show tables" mysql throws one of this errors.

Comment: May be your `connect_timeout` value is set to only a few seconds in **my.cnf** file. Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually, because of connect timeout problem

Try increasing connect_timeout in your my.cnf file

On FreeBSD this happens because there was no match found in /etc/hosts.allow. Adding the following line before the line saying ALL:ALL fixes this:

```
  mysqld: ALL: allow
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the bind-adress in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. The value must be 127.0.0.1
This issue can lead to error 2002